# How To Sort And Reindex Numbered List Index On Unordered List In HTML?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I need to sort and reindex the following numbered, unordered sample list.

```
<ul>
   <li>0001 - Apple</li>
   <li>0002 - Banana</li>
   <li>0003 - Mango</li>
</ul>
```

Where the "0001 - Apple" is moved down as follows.

```
<ul>
   <li>0002 - Banana</li>
   <li>0003 - Mango</li>
   <li>0001 - Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Where it is supposed to be as the following list.

```
<ul>
   <li>0001 - Banana</li>
   <li>0002 - Mango</li>
   <li>0003 - Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Another issue raises when I move a list item one row down.

```
<ul>
   <li>0002 - Mango</li>
   <li>0001 - Banana</li>
   <li>0003 - Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Or for example I move a list item one row up.

```
<ul>
   <li>0002 - Mango</li>
   <li>0003 - Apple</li>
   <li>0001 - Banana</li>       
</ul>
```

All of each index is supposed to be "0001", "0002", "0003" respectively.

The movement is triggered by buttons for moving upward or moving downward.

Comment: Other than the word Apple goes to bottom what are all the granular criteria? Also what have you tried?

Comment: I would like to reindex the number regardless the word(s) adjacent to that. I have tried using jQuery but it failed.

Comment: So only move 001? Still a bit unclear. Also is it possible to add another element for the numbers like a span in the source of the html or only get what is shown?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do.  `I need to sort` - surely both `001` and `Apple` should be at the top then? Or did you mean sort in reverse order?

Comment: I have edited the question. The additional explanation describes what I would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

Based on only moving 001 to the bottom and maintaining the same order of the others try the following:

```js
const $ul = $('ul');

$ul.append($ul.children().filter(':contains(001)'));// or if move top to bottom use `first()`

$ul.children().text((i, txt) => {
  let parts = txt.split('-');
  parts[0] = (i + 1).toString().padStart(3, '0');
  return parts.join(' -');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>0001 - Apple</li>
  <li>0002 - Banana</li>
  <li>0003 - Mango</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However another issue raises if we move up and move down the list item for only one row. It's not only move from top to bottom or vice versa.

Comment: That's why I tried asking what ***all*** the criteria are

Comment: Also you've given no indication of how these moves would be triggered